# trouble importing a list from a module

Tags: python, list, import, module

Hello I am using python and I'm having trouble importing data from one file to another file the file whose data I am trying to import is called 'data' I am trying to import a list that is in the 'data' file this list is called 'stats' I tried importing the 'stats' list like this:

```py
from data import stats
from data.py import stats
from C:\Users\Documents\data.py import stats
```

How do I make a module and how would I import my `stats` list from my `data` file?

Comment: put data.py in the same directory as your script, then use `from data import stats`

Comment: What error do you get when you run each of the code snippets in your question?

Comment: for (from data import stats) and (from data.py import stat) I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'  and for (from C:\Users\Documents\data.py import stats) I got invalid syntax

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I've saved it as data

Comment: @muffinman please could you edit your question to include the details about the error messages? It might also help to include some minimal example code from data.py and the script which attempts the import, as well as some indication of the directory structure.

Comment: "...I've saved it as data" -- did you literally save it as just "data" and not as "data.py"?

Comment: I literally saved it as just 'data'

Comment: please save it as data.py then do as suggested.